# Popover truncated when inside a collapsed navbar, in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Setting up the question, here is the *situation*, the *problem*, the *screenshot*, and the *code*:

**The situation:**

- In my responsive `bootstrap3` layout, there is a `navbar` which is `fixed-top`.
- I have the `collapse` information in place, as shown in the documentation.
- There is a button/link in the `navbar` which invokes a `popover`.

**The problem:**

When the `navbar` is in its collapsed state, the `popover` is hidden within the scrollable area allotted to the `navbar` options.

**The screenshot:**

[image]

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-topnav">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
        Unearth Synergy
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-topnav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a popover="signin_form" href="#">Sign In<span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[popover]',
    placement: "auto bottom",
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return $('#'+$(this).attr("popover")).html();
    }
});
```

**So how do I show the popover *outside* the collapsed `navbar` in the main content area itself?**

I obviously do not want the content in the popover to be locked within the scrollable region caused by `bootstrap` allocating a fixed-height scrollable region for `navbar` items.

I've seen questions similar to this asked about `dropdown` elements, but nothing about `popover` elements which are an entirely different situation. Since this issue seems to be relevant to `bootstrap` use, I am posting it, answering it, and leaving this at the point where a slight improvement can be made if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

With `container: ‘body’` added to the JavaScript declaration of the popover, the following now occurs, which is closer:

[image: SS]

The `popover` is now under the `navbar`.

But with this CSS augmentation, along with the JavaScript tweak, the problem is solved… basically:

```
.popover.in {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The last (purely aesthetic) issue is now that the `popover` arrow and content are oriented to the expanded link as a whole, rather than to the icon and text of the link contents.

That is expectable, and there is no usability impediment, and so the issue is solved:

[image]